# How to add CAPTCHA on a Cognito Form?

Tags: cognito-forms, captcha

I want a CAPTCHA on my form to prevent spam. How can I get it since it is not in the tools?

Answer (score 2):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms.

Spam prevention is automatic for Cognito Forms.  Bots will see the Captcha, humans won't.

https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/spam-prevention